# Adding folder in Internal Storage in public?

Tags: android, jxls

am create the **Excel file** to store it in Internal storage,but am not able to do.It Create only inside the app storage directory.Not to visible in public.How to create folder and store the file in that folder?Can anyone one know help me to solve this issue.

**File Creation coding**

```
 public String generate(String file_name,String path) {

    try {

        f = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), path);
        if (!f.exists()) {
           f.mkdirs();
        }


        file = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(), file_name);
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        wb_setting = new WorkbookSettings();
        wb_setting.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wb_setting);
        workbook.createSheet("Report", 0);
        excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        createLabel(excelSheet);
        createContent(excelSheet);

        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();

        file_path_alert_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        file_path_alert_builder.setTitle("File path");
        file_path_alert_builder.setMessage(""+file).setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.dismiss();

            }
        });

        file_path_dialog = file_path_alert_builder.create();
        file_path_dialog.show();
    }catch (JXLException jxl_e) {
        jxl_e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to choose the right path where to store the files. There are multiple options

Internal storage

- internal to app (not accessible for end users from outside)
- cache directory (it can be cleared if system is running out of space)

External Storage (verify if it is available and use it) Although it is public there are 2 types

- public
- private (technically accessible by the user and other apps because they are on the external storage, they are files that realistically don't provide value to the user outside your app. )

each path location can be accessed with different API provided by android. see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: okay,but some popular application like What's,Viber,camscanner application have the folder to show the files in internal storage.

Comment: they use external storage. getExternalFilesDir() can be used.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by visible to public? Access by other applications? If that is the case, using:
`getExternalFilesDir()` instead

Comment: When user open the internal storage means the folder will visible.

Comment: Then you should use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` which suggest by @Aun. Please note that  "external storage" can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage