# how to crop image and save them in app's cache memory or hidden folder in Android

Tags: android, image, sqlite, caching, android-fragments

So far I manage to select image from gallery and save it's link in SQLite. And I'm able to retrieve it into imageview. Now I want to crop the image and save the cropped image into cache folder. I want to do this because my app is crashing due to lack of image size.

This is the code:

```
    ((Button) gv.findViewById(R.id.ETPetImg))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                            //intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                            //intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                            //intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                            //intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                            //intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                            //intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                        }
                    }); 

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri); //To get image path
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                //imgBtn.setI

            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        //Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

As you can see I already got the answer for cropping image but I need answer for saving the image into cache and save the cache links to SQLite. And it would be great if someone can answer how to keep the image size lower(150kb) when saving into cache. Please answer with Android Java code?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned - cropping code is already done.

Where to store the cropped image - database may not be right choice

save the cropped images in the private application folder or external application cache directory and also store its link in the sqlite db like you store it for full image.

see [Adding folder in Internal Storage in public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731195/adding-folder-in-internal-storage-in-public/26731619#26731619)  for more details on options where you can store the files

Comment: can you please provide me some sample codes or just modify my code as per my requirement.Since am an beginner in android development.

Answer (score 0):

please see the following for cropping the image and saving to gallery

> **Manifest file :**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.satis.crop_success">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

> **Main_activity.java**

```java
    package com.example.satis.crop_success;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
    import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;

    import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
    import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AppSettingsDialog;
    import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.io.File;
    import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
    import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private int REQ_CODE = 1;
        private ImageView mImageView;
        Uri uri;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri tempUri = data.getData();
                CropImage.activity(tempUri)
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                        .start(this);
                Log.d("TAG", "MUR: result worked");
            }
            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                //Uri Of Cropped Image:
                Uri imageUri = result.getUri();

                mImageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "cropped" , "cropped");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

> **Layout file :**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.cursedcompany.androidclassroomimagecrop.MainActivity">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:id="@+id/image_view"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Click To select Image"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **Gradle:(under app module)**

```java
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.satis.crop_success"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0'
        implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.2.0'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    }
    allprojects {


        gradle.projectsEvaluated {
            tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
                options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
            }
        }
    }
```